# How to use MySQL functions with criteriaBuilder

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, specifications, criteriabuilder

I want get `Specification<Entity>`. I am use **criteriaBuilder** in my code. I have only start_date and duration. please refer table structure.

```
start_date | duration |
-----------|----------|
2022-06-07 |     10   |
2022-06-23 |      6   |
```

Please refer code example. I want to use.  `expireDate = start_date + duration`

```
Specification<Entity> endDateSpec = (root, query, criteriaBuilder)->criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("expireDate"), Date.valueOf('2022-06-07'));
```

please help me to write correct code according below code.

Comment: Try to get not `expireDate` column (which not exist really as I have understood) value but an expression `start_date + INTERVAL duration DAYS` value (maybe as raw SQL).

Comment: I use JPA. in this I use **start_date** as "startDate"

Comment: Anycase the expression `start_date + duration` is not correct in MySQL. I provide correct syntax - use it literally.

Comment: can you share that?

Answer (score 0):

```
start_date, duration, DATE_ADD(`start_date`, INTERVAL `duration` DAY)AS expireDate FROM tableName
```

Comment: expireDate? **Specification<Entity> endDateSpec = (root, query, criteriaBuilder)->criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("start_date, duration, DATE_ADD(`start_date`, INTERVAL `duration` DAY)AS expireDate FROM tableName"), Date.valueOf('2022-06-07'));** It's that correct?